# C++ unknown override specifier when using strings

Tags: c++, string

I've trying to solve this problem for a long time now:

I have the following class (Doctor):

Doctor.h:

```
    #pragma once
    class Doctor
    {
    private:
         string firstName;
    public:
        Doctor();
        ~Doctor();
    };
```

Doctor.cpp:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include "string"
    #include "Doctor.h"

    using namespace std;

    Doctor::Doctor()
    {
    }


    Doctor::~Doctor()
    {
    }
```

and my main function:

```
   #include "stdafx.h"
   #include <string>
   #include "Doctor.h"

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
       return 0;
   }
```

Error   C3646   'firstName': unknown override specifier

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

Error   C3646   'firstName': unknown override specifier

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

all at line 5 of Doctor.h where I declare a string variable

Comment: `#include <string>` + `std::string`

Comment: How long is "a long time"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps

```
<string> header is missing.
```

Try including it.

Doctor.h

```
#ifndef DOCTOR_H_
#define DOCTOR_H_

#include <string>

class Doctor{
    std::string name;
public:
    Doctor();
    ~Doctor();
};
#endif
```

Doctor.cpp

```
#include "Doctor.h"

Doctor::Doctor()
{
}

Doctor::~Doctor()
{
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "Doctor.h"
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

It is working fine. I have tested.

Comment: include in the header, not in the cpp

Comment: Names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_DOCTOR_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved to the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: Its perfectly fine. In fact the standard way is to start header guards with underscore and capital letter only. Only double underscore is reserved. http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/71787/

Comment: @abhishekkumar `17.6.4.3.2/1.1 Each name that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.` I recommend using the standard document as the authority on what is reserved and what is not, rather than an arbitrary message board.

Comment: so every time I declare a string I must

Comment: @ODDdaaaaai in general, every time you declare **any** variable of a class type (i.e. not a [fundamental type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)), the type must be defined. `std::string` is defined in `<string>`, so if you declare one, then you must include the definition.

Comment: @abhishekkumar:  General rule of thumb:  Don't try and pick an argument with Pete Becker about the details of the C++ standard.  He has been the editor of the committee in the past (he may still be).  He also has implemented the Dinkumware C++ Standard Library (which had to make sure to *only* use identifiers reserved to the implementation, so it didn't conflict with a user macro).

Comment: use `std::string` or add the line `using namespace std;` on top.

Answer (score 6):

You need to `#include <string>` in `Doctor.h`, and you need the standard namespace `std::string`.

Comment: I edited my code, but I'm still getting the same errors